# How to focus and activate a vue multiselect?

Tags: vuejs2

When the user double-clicks this:

```
<div 
  class="open-select" 
  v-if="!editable" 
  @dblclick="editable=true">{{ name }} 
</div>
```

I'd like this multiselect to be open and focused:

```
<multiselect
    v-else
    v-model="name"
    :options="names"
    track-by="id"
    tabindex="0"
    autofocus
    @select="editable=false"
></multiselect>
```

The double-click event shows the multiselect element fine, **but the multiselect still requires the user to click it to open.** I'd like it to open automatically after appearing.

Things I've tried:

- focusing the multiselect:

  - tabindex="0"
  - autofocus
  - When I try to select the focused item in jQuery, `$(':focus')[0]`, I get 'undefined'

Comment: that's going to depend on whatever third-party component you're using for the "multiselect". If that component has an API that allows setting focus, use it. Otherwise, you're likely out of luck.

Comment: @StephenThomas I think it's [vue-multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/), I mean, right? I'm not sure what else it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out how to do this *(ref didn't work for me)*:

***STEP 1: I was focusing on the wrong element.***

So a vue-multiselect element is structured like this (shorthand to only show important parts):

```
<div class="multiselect"> // <= This is the element to focus on
  <div class="multiselect__tags">
    <input>               // <= Not the input
  </div>
</div>
```

Typically you want to put your `tabindex` on the input, instead you should put it on the parent with a class of `multiselect`. This also goes for things like jQuery's `focus()`. So...

No: `$('.multiselect input').focus()`

Yes: `$('.multiselect').focus()`

***STEP 2: Correcting tabindex.***

Another issue is when vue-multiselect puts a `tabindex="-1"` on all `.multiselect` elements. This removes them from the natural order of tabindexes, so you need to reassign all the tabindexes:

In [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) and [updated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) (if necessary) you need code to reassign all the tabindexes:

```
mounted: function() {
    $(document).ready(()=>{

        // you may need to delete all tabindexes first.
        $('[tabindex]').each( (i,v) => {
            $(v).removeAttr('tabindex');
            return true;
        });

        // add new tabindexes
        $('input, textarea, button').each(( i,v ) => {
            var isMultiSelect = $(v).hasClass('multiselect__input');

            if(isMultiSelect){
                $(v).parents('.multiselect:first').attr('tabindex', i + 1);
            else{
                $(v).attr('tabindex', i + 1);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Heyo!

You can put a ref on the component and then trigger focus which will open the dropdown.

```
<multiselect ref="vms" v-bind="yourAttributes" />
```

And then in your created hook you add

```
this.$refs.vms.$el.focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

**A simplest solution - Toggle Vue Multiselect dropdown**

You can use 2 events (@open, @close) on VueMultiselect
anda ref in multiselect
like

```
ref="multiselect"
```

keep in

```
data(){
  isOpen: false
}
```

then add to the 2 events

```
 @close="isOpen = false"
 @open="isOpen = true"
```

and use a method

```
 toggle() {
            if (this.isOpen) {
                this.$refs.multiselect.$el.blur()
                this.isOpen = false
            } else {
                this.$refs.multiselect.$el.focus()
                this.isOpen = true
            }
        }
```